# How much is the cost for a team to be registered in the CONCACAF Champions League?

Tags: rules, football, finances, concacaf

I'm wondering how much is the cost for a team to be registered in the CONCACAF Champions League. E.g, let's say the champion club from Haiti wants to play in the first phase of the CONCACAF Champions League against Caribbean teams. Do they have to pay to play the tournament? How much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually such prestigious continental tournaments don't require entrance payments, instead they require the proofs for financial stability of the entrants. From [CONCACAF Champions League Regulations](https://www.concacafchampionsleague.com/en/regulations) - III. ENTRIES AND WITHDRAWALS - Entry Criteria,

> C. As a matter of principle, clubs will earn the right to be entered
>   by their Association into the competition through:
>
> 1. Fair play and sporting merit;
> 2. Compliance with their Association’s Regional Club Licensing requirements;
> 3. Financial good standing with their Association and CONCACAF.

CONCACAF has other means of making money though (part of which is later redistributed between participating clubs as participation fee or prize money), e.g, from V. FINANCIAL PROVISIONS - Revenue:

> Participating clubs agree to pay 5% of the gross ticket revenues (or a
>   minimum of $500.00 USD) to CONCACAF for each match within 30 days
>   after each match.

Or from XIV. MARKETING RIGHTS AND OBLIGATIONS,

> K. CONCACAF, as the licensor, will have the right to receive 80% of
>   the event specific Merchandise Revenue.

---

Regarding the clubs from Caribbean Zone (where Haiti belongs to), the clubs from Caribbean associations first need to play in the Caribbean Club Championship (also called Tier 1), from where only the winners qualify for the CONCACAF Champions League. According to [CONCACAF website](http://www.concacaf.com/article/concacaf-announces-expanded-concacaf-caribbean-club-championship-for-2018),

> The Tier 1 Caribbean Club Championship, which launches on January 31,
>   2018, will feature eight professional clubs from four Member
>   Associations – the Dominican Republic, Haiti, Jamaica and Trinidad &
>   Tobago. The Tier 2 competition will consist of clubs from twelve
>   Caribbean Member Association leagues that do not presently meet the
>   minimum CONCACAF Club Licensing requirements.

Here is some more information about [club licencing](http://www.concacaf.com/en/article/concacaf-club-licensing-at-work-in-bonaire) from CONCACAF.

In its [statutes](http://www.cfufootball.org/documents/cfu-statutes-22-may-2012-edition.pdf), Caribbean Football Union (which organizes Caribbean Club Championship) defines similar to CONCACAF criteria for entering competitions played under its auspices and there is no mention of entrance fee.